# Best way to sort the TreeMap by values

Tags: nearprotocol

My program needs to sort the TreeMap values. But values can be in 100,000. I am planning to use merge sort for it. How much gas/dollar will be required for the calculation? What will be the best and efficient way for finding N highest number?
TreeMap has sorting by keys not value.
https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.TreeMap.html#method.iter_rev

Comment: What do "dollars" and "gas" have to do with a data structure?

Comment: In blockchain, computational complexity costs gas.

Comment: You're speaking in riddles.  How do you determine the amount of petroleum product consumed for a computation?

Comment: This is my code with solution suggested by Evgeny https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTDUwhMyV7AhxdNnS4qZ2iVn5TXqJTGQyCEXE7XE74mfh/Rust--Near_Protocol--Approval_Voting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the blockchain part for now.

If you need to have order on values in addition to the order on keys, you can use another data structure such as `TreeSet<(Value, Key)>` that uses tuples of Value and Key as a sorting key. When updating a `TreeMap`, you also update the `TreeSet`. To iterate on the values in the reverse order, you can use reverse iterator of the `TreeSet`. Having a pair instead of just a `Value` allows you to disambiguate the same values, but also having an associated `Key` for each value.

Now to implement this on NEAR.

Since we currently don't have `TreeSet`, you can just use another `TreeMap<(Value, Key), ()>`

Answer (score 0):

A complete re-sort by value is likely to be an O(*K* log *K*) operation, where *K* = number of entries in the original TreeMap, which I think was stated as approximately 100,000.

So  *K* log *K* is about 1.7 million operations (log 100,000 is a little less than 17), if my loose arithmetic is correct.

If the number of entries we're looking for, *N*, is small compared to *K*, then we can probably do better.

Pseudocode:

```
 top N := first N elements from original collection
 min value := smallest value of the top N
 for each remaining element in original collection:
     if element value > min value:
          replace corresponding element in top N
          min value := smallest value now in top N
```

So, this makes one pass through the original collection. Assuming (hand-wave) that about half the time we hit the 'element value > min value' condition, and thus have to locate the new smallest element.

Each 'locate the smallest' is O(log *N*) assuming sorted collection.  We're doing that *K*/2 times, so *K*/2 log *N* operations total, plus the *K* for the traversal through the original collection.

Let's put *N* = 10.  So that's 50,000 log 10 + 100,000, or about 300,000, an improvement on 1.7 million.

But the viability of this depends a lot on what *N* is.